# Nextjs Link Preview on Social Sites Dynamic Meta Tags

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

i have migrated my codebase from React Typescript to React Next Typescript just to make the Open Graph preview links working once they shared on social sites.

i have a page that fetches data from my backend based on passed id i just want to render the title and description of the incoming data in to meta tags so facebook can show those details once that url being entered. is any thing i'm missing here.

i'm using redux for state management and saga for api handing etc. you can see the data in cardsData.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Center, Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CardDetailsComponent from "shared/components/card-details/card-details-component";
import { RootState } from "store";
import { getCardByIdRequest } from "store/actions/card-api/card-api-action-creators";
import { getImageUrl } from "utils/getImageUtils";
import CardSkeltonComponent from "shared/components/card-skelton/card-skelton-component";
import Head from 'next/head'

const CardDetailsPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cardId = "61ac9939b44eac00473790f8";
  function getCardData() {
    dispatch(getCardByIdRequest(cardId));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getCardData();
  }, []);

  const { loading, isError, data } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.cardsData
  );

  return (
    <Box>
      <Head>
        {data && (
          <>
            <title>{data?.cardDetails.title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={data?.cardDetails?.description} />
          </>
        )}
      </Head>
      {loading ? (
        <Center style={{ width: '50%', margin: '10% 0% 0% 25%' }}>
          {' '}
          <CardSkeltonComponent
            isCardInFullWidth={true}
            numberofCards={1}
          />{' '}
        </Center>
      ) : isError ? (
        <Center h="80vh" w="full"></Center>
      ) : (
        data && (
          <>
            <CardDetailsComponent
              title={data?.cardDetails.title}
              description={data?.cardDetails?.description}
              backgroundImage={getImageUrl(data?.heroMedia)}
            />
          </>
        )
      )}
    </Box>
  )
};
export default CardDetailsPage;
```

Comment: And what exactly is the issue? You're making the request in the client-side only, `data` won't be available when the page gets pre-rendered on the server.

Comment: https://medium.com/wesionary-team/customize-social-media-preview-of-your-nextjs-website-links-82f6bce035b
Check out this article. You need to fetch the data from your server using getServerSideProps and pass it as meta tags in your <Head> element